# Returning START_NOT_STICKY is redundant for action of STOP (stopForeground and stopSelf)?

Tags: java, android, service

when concerning the implementation of the method onStartCommand() I always use the following architecture.
In my `FatherService.class` I implement basically just the **STOP** of the service:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null) {
            if (action.equals("STOP")) {
                stopForeground(true);
                stopSelf();

                return START_NOT_STICKY;
            }
        }

        ...

        //return START_STICKY;
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }
```

I was wondering if returning START_NOT_STICKY is redundant since when the service is killed by the user (and not by the system) the service will never be restarted anyway.

Comment: Reduntant or not, you're required to return an `int` flag either way, so just leave it as it is.